# Is there any ants on you?

Tags: grammar

He sat on the ground and ants crawled up and bit him.

I discovered it and quickly removed them.

"**Is there any ants on you?**" I asked him as I am not sure I have removed all of them.

Does it sound grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **are** instead of *is* as *ants* is plural.

> **Are** there any ants on you?